# five:protectName error with allowed_interfaces and allowed_attributes

Tags: plone, zope

in my browser / configure.zcml I've putted a directive to manage a view with a specific interface and method, in this way:

```xml
<browser:page
    for="my.package.interfaces.ICartellaBandidiLavoro"
    name="lavoroautonomo"
    class=".cartellabandiview.cartellabandiView"
    template="cartellabandiview.pt"
    allowed_interface=".cartellabandiview.ICartellabandiView"
    allowed_attributes="rss_bandi"
    permission="zope.Public"
    />
```

in the cartellabandiview.py I have

```python
[...]
class ICartellabandiView(Interface):
    """ cartellabandi view interface """

def rss_bandi():
    """ rss """
```

when I start the instance I obtain an error

```
 raise ConfigurationConflictError(conflicts)
 zope.configuration.config.ConfigurationConflictError: Conflicting configuration actions
 For: ('five:protectName', <class 'Products.Five.metaclass.SimpleViewClass from /Users/vito/repos/my.package/my/package/browser/cartellabandiview.pt'>, u'rss_bandi')
```

Any suggestions?

Vito

Comment: imho you cannot use `allowed_interface` and `allowed_attributes`at the same time. You're fine with `allowed_interface`.

Comment: Just tested, no success :(

Comment: what means no success? same error??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code you pasted is right, probably is only an indentation problem. `rss_bandi` is not a method inside the `ICartellaView` class. it seems is an external module level function.

As Mathias noted already noted: yes, you only need `allowed_interface`.